# Twitter/Facebook login for comments

Tags: comments, facebook, twitter

What plug-ins there are available to allow people to leave comments using their Facebook and Twitter logins? Any special considerations or recommendations?

I am currently allowing comments with the email addresses (default setup), but there are certain problems in this approach (spam being one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [Simple Facebook Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/) and [Simple Twitter Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/) have features to allow users to post comments using their Facebook or Twitter credentials. Among other things.

Disclaimer: I wrote 'em both.

Comment: why Simple Twitter Connect is not in the repository?

Comment: It ceased to work properly when Twitter made changes to their API. I have not had time to fix it, so I removed it until I could find the time to do so.

Answer (score 2):

[Disqus](http://disqus.com/) is a popular cross-site comment system which allows logging in via various methods, including Twitter, Facebook and your own disqus account. They obviously have their own [Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/) you should check out.

Comment: I'd still like to host comments on the site itself. Disqus advanced API options are very pricey.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Facebook Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-for-wordpress/) This is the best plugin for facebook comments and For [twitter comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitoaster/screenshots/).

Hope Both are very helpful.